# PHPMailer - The attachment is sent but the form is not reset

Tags: javascript, php, forms, email, phpmailer

I have two different files (.pdf) to send based on the selection made by the user. In practice, when the user selects the select 'user', he must send the attachment associated with that selection. By adding the code in the PHP file, the submission occurs but the form is not reset.
Am I wrong in doing the file selection? Only the file of array "0" is sent, even if the second select is selected

This is select:

```
<select name="user" id="user">
 <option disabled selected>Richiesta prestazione per</option>
 <option value="adulti">Adulti</option>
 <option value="minori">Minorenni</option>
</select>
```

This is PHPMailer:

```
    <?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

// Instantiation and passing [ICODE]true[/ICODE] enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true)
  
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
//$user = $_POST['user']; // i tried to disable this //
$pay = $_POST['pay'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
$cod = mt_rand(100000, 999999);

//replacing them with this
$user = array (0 => './documents/test.pdf', 1 => './documents/test2.pdf');
$file = $user[(int) $_POST['user']];

try {
 //Server settings
 //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // Enable verbose debug output
 $mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
 $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
 $mail->Host = '_MYMAIL_'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
 $mail->Username = '_MYMAIL_'; // SMTP username
 $mail->Password = '_MYPASS_'; // SMTP password
 $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
 $mail->Port = 587; // TCP port to connect to

//Recipients
 $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
 $mail->addAddress('_MYMAIL_', '_MYNAME_'); // Add a recipient
 $mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);

// Content
 $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
 $mail->Subject = "\xF0\x9F\x93\x86 Richiesta di Consulenza Online";
 $mail->Body = _MYMESSAGE_;

 if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message sent';
}

$mail->ClearAddresses();
$mail->ClearaddReplyTo();

// Add the admin address
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->setFrom('_MYMAIL_', '_MYNAME_');
$mail->Subject = _MYSUBJECT_;
$mail->addReplyTo('_MYMAIL_', '_MYNAME_');
$mail->AddAttachment($file) **//I add this to attach the .pdf file**
$mail->Body = 

<body>
 
   <h2>Codice prenotazione: '.$cod.'</h2>
 
   <table>
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Nome</th>
         <th>Cognome</th>
         <th>Adulto/Minore</th>
         <th>Pagamento</th>
         <th>Telefono</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>'.$name.'</td>
         <td>'.$surname.'</td>
         <td>'.$user.'</td> //this is line 114
         <td>'.$pay.'</td>
         <td>'.$phone.'</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td colspan="5">Messaggio:<br><br>'.$message.'</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </body>;

$mail->Send();


} catch (Exception $e) {
 echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

And this is call Ajax in file .js:

```
    $("#formBook").submit(function (event) {
    // cancels the form submission
    event.preventDefault();
    submitForm();
  });
  
  function submitForm() {
     //Initiate Variables With Form Content
     var name = $("#name").val();
     var surname = $("#surname").val();
     var email = $("#email").val();
     var phone = $("#phone").val();
     var user = $("#user").val();
     var message = $("#message").val();
     var pay = $("#pay").val();
  
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "email_monia.php",
      data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message + "&user=" + user + "&phone=" + phone + "&pay=" + pay + "&surname=" + surname,
      success: function (data) {
        if (data == 'Message sent') {
          formSuccess();
        }
      }
    });
  }

function formSuccess() {
$("#formBook")[0].reset();
// custom toast
iziToast.show({
  color: 'light',
  icon: 'fas fa-paper-plane',
  message: '<strong>Grazie!</strong></br>Il tuo messaggio è stato inviato',
  messageLineHeight: 20,
  messageSize: 15,
  position: 'center', // bottomRight, bottomLeft, topRight, topLeft, topCenter, bottomCenter
  progressBarColor: '#00909D',
  backgroundColor: ' #9ad3ca',
  titleColor: '#222',
  messageColor: '#222',
  iconColor: '#F7F7F7',
  closa: false,
  displayMode: 'once',
  pauseOnHover: false,
  resetOnHover: false,
});
}
```

Comment: use `$_POST`  to get the data, then use a simple `if` to change document

Comment: with the postal code I can receive the pdf file, but I always receive the same file even selecting the other option of the select.

Comment: What do you mean by "form is not reset"? Shouldn't there be any code to handle this? When you are using AJAX to submit the form, resetting it should also take place using JS (which makes this question completely independent from the PHP code)

Comment: i edited the post with the js code that is run for reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are submitting name in `user` field instead of index, in that case you should update your attachment array to an associative array

```
//replacing them with this
$user = array ( 
    'adulti' => './documents/test.pdf',
    'minori' => './documents/test.pdf'
);
$file = $user[$_POST['user']];
```

In the `formSuccess` function

```
$("#formBook").reset();
```

Can you verify your response

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "email_monia.php",
  data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message + "&user=" + user + "&phone=" + phone + "&pay=" + pay + "&surname=" + surname,
  success: function (data) {
    // check response here
    console.log(data);
    if (data == 'Message sent') {
      formSuccess();
    }
  }
```

Comment: yes, with this change it now works! Send the different file based on your selection. But now I can't get the form reset to work and get the submission message to appear

Comment: did you `console.log` and verify you are getting expected response `Message sent`

Comment: where should I enter the console.log?

Comment: your modification to the array works, but now I return the value "Array" and not the value of the select in the user field of the form. Is there a way to make me return the value of the select field?

Comment: i am not sure what you mean? check my updated answer as how to log and confirm your response

Comment: Ok, as for the console.log, it returns me this:  `Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\webImago\email_monia.php on line 114`. For the other question, I try to receive the value "Adults" - "Minors" in the table I receive via email via 'user', only I receive the value 'Array' - Update the code with line 114

Comment: I tried to delete the line 114 it was telling me. Now I don't get that message anymore, the `console.log` just gives me `Message Sent` and the form is not reset

Comment: may be `console.log(data == 'Message sent')` ?

Comment: `$user` is the attachment array, you can use `$_POST['user']` in line `114` to get the value

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
Now everything works correctly

Answer (score 0):

Your JS is responsible for doing this. You are calling `event.preventDefault();`, but then not doing anything to clear the form yourself, so nothing happens. You need to tell the form to reset explicitly, for example by calling this in your `formSuccess()` function:

```
document.getElementById("formBook").reset();
```

In your PHP, don't use the submitter's address as the from address. Use your own address there and put the submitter's address in a reply-to using `addReplyTo()`. Otherwise it will be forgery and your messages probably won't be delivered.

Comment: I skipped a piece of code, wrote the command I have for reset

Comment: the weird thing is that if I delete all the attachment part, the reset command works fine